# Selection Failure Exepction in BPEL Composite

Tags: oracle, soap, soa, bpel

i have simple bpel process that recieve input , assign input to call remote webservice , then assign response to output variable

[image]

the problem is when assign the respose from the remote webservice to the output of the bpel process i get the following exception

```
oracle.j2ee.ws.common.jaxws.JAXWSMessageLogger> <JAXWSMessageLogger> <errorLogException> <Error while invoking endpoint "http://osmohame-eg.eg.oracle.com:7101/soa-infra/services/default/HelloBpel/hellobpel_client_ep" from client; Security Subject: AdminChannelUsers> 
java.lang.Exception: oracle.sysman.emInternalSDK.webservices.util.SoapTestException: Client received SOAP Fault from server : faultName: {{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure}
messageType: {{http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension}RuntimeFaultMessage}


    at oracle.sysman.emas.model.wsmgt.WSTestModel.invokeOperation(WSTestModel.java:1745)
    at oracle.sysman.emas.view.wsmgt.WSView.invokeOperation(WSView.java:565)
    at oracle.sysman.emas.view.wsmgt.WSView.invokeTest(WSView.java:408)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.util.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:53)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.broadcastToMethodBinding(UIXComponentBase.java:1988)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:183)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:111)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:115)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1243)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeInvokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:686)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:364)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:227)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:207)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adf.view.page.editor.webapp.WebCenterComposerFilter.doFilter(WebCenterComposerFilter.java:119)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFFilter.doFilter(ServletADFFilter.java:77)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.help.web.rich.OHWFilter.doFilter(OHWFilter.java:95)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.EMRepLoginFilter.doFilter(EMRepLoginFilter.java:729)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:274)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.sysman.emas.fwk.MASConnectionFilter.doFilter(MASConnectionFilter.java:50)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.MBeanServerConnFilter.doFilter(MBeanServerConnFilter.java:43)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.ContextInitFilter.doFilter(ContextInitFilter.java:561)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.caching.filter.AdfFacesCachingFilterImpl.doFilter(AdfFacesCachingFilterImpl.java:134)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.webapp.AdfFacesCachingFilter.doFilter(AdfFacesCachingFilter.java:66)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.sysman.core.app.exception.EMRuntimeExceptionFilter.doFilter(EMRuntimeExceptionFilter.java:81)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$3.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:172)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:110)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilterInternal(JpsAbsFilter.java:273)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:147)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused by: oracle.sysman.emInternalSDK.webservices.util.SoapTestException: Client received SOAP Fault from server : faultName: {{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure}
messageType: {{http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension}RuntimeFaultMessage}


    at oracle.sysman.emInternalSDK.webservices.impl.ServiceDispatchImpl.invoke(ServiceDispatchImpl.java:527)
    at oracle.sysman.emInternalSDK.webservices.impl.OperationInfoImpl.invokeWithDispatch(OperationInfoImpl.java:1191)
    at oracle.sysman.emas.model.wsmgt.PortName.invokeOperation(PortName.java:935)
    at oracle.sysman.emas.model.wsmgt.WSTestModel.invokeOperation(WSTestModel.java:1727)
    ... 104 more
Caused by: oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.JRFSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server : faultName: {{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure}
messageType: {{http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension}RuntimeFaultMessage}

    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.DispatchImpl.throwJAXWSSoapFaultException(DispatchImpl.java:1833)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.DispatchImpl.invoke(DispatchImpl.java:1408)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.OracleDispatchImpl.synchronousInvocationWithRetry(OracleDispatchImpl.java:238)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.OracleDispatchImpl.invoke(OracleDispatchImpl.java:109)
    at oracle.sysman.emInternalSDK.webservices.impl.ServiceDispatchImpl.invoke(ServiceDispatchImpl.java:523)
    ... 107 more
```

also i noticed strange problem 
when i'm doing the mapping from remote service respone to the bpel output , jdevloper make the line from the part1 to payload , and i need to write ns2:creditcardstatus (which is the response ) by myself

also the composite xml show the following warnings :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got (*selectionFailure* ) exception, that means the creditcardStatus is empty to avoid this issue you can add **`ignoreMissingFromData="yes"`** in the assign component as below

```
<copy ignoreMissingFromData="yes">
            <from>$inputVariable.payload/ns3:documentId</from>
            <to expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">$Invoke_Notifications_InputVariable.request/ns3:documentId</to>
          </copy>
```